# what does string matching "s/\r\n/ /g" mean in perl

Tags: string, perl

Can someone explain what does this string matching command do in Perl

```
 $CAD_Line=~s/\r\n/ /g;
```

where can I get additional information on this type of matching?(What do I search for?)

Comment: http://regexr.com/ is helpful

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It replaces each instance of the sequence Carriage Return (U+000D) followed by Line Feed (U+000A) with a space.

- The substitution operator (`s///`) is documented in [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html).
- Regular expressions are documented in [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html).

  - `\r` matches a Carriage Return (U+000D).
  - `\n` matches a Line Feed (U+000A).

If you want a tutorial rather than a reference, checkout [perlretut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html)

Answer (score 1):

$CAD_Line=~s/\r\n/ /g;

Substitute carriage return and line feed with a space. The trailing g means globally.  So if you have an entire file in the $CAD_Line variable, it would remove all instances of \r\n, not just the first one. This is called a regular expression or "regex" and is the most often cited feature of the Perl language.

It should be noted that different operating systems and file types use different line feed characters.  \r\n is a windows type format whearas unix/linux and apple/mac will use \n  newline.

Whole books have been written on regular expressions.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/perl/perl_regular_expression.htm